# i want 3 pages of my wordpress website password protected, so when the user log in, only then he will be able to see those pages

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

http://www.sigd.org/training/teacher-sigd/

Here User need to login, then after login he will be redirected to password protected page, from there he can navigate to other password protected pages with no prompt again for password

I have a plugin , in it after login we are able to navigate to all password protected pages, but sometimes it ask for password after we login and try to navigate different password protected page.

May be this is because of cookie this plugin using

May be if we use session then this will be solved

I am using "Smart Passworded Pages " wordpress plugin

Answer (score 0):

@ankita,

You can set the visibility to password protected on that specific page right side on the dashboard without any plugin. Check on the password protected and then publish. Kindly check the added screenshot.

[image]